# Can't pass data from view to controller

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter-3

I have a strange problem.
I can't pass the data from form to controller. I think my code was right, but I don't know why it can't pass the data- and always says "failed". I've tried to print the data that I post, but it says 'no data'.
Maybe there is something I forgot to do, and can you help me?

Here's my code

view code :

```
<div id="register" class="text-center">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="section-title center">
      <h2>Register</h2>
      <hr>
      <form action="<?php echo base_url('c_register/do_insert'); ?>" method="post">
      <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/user/css/login.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
      <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo form_error("firstname"); ?></span>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
      <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo form_error("lasttname"); ?></span>
      <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" placeholder="Full Name">
      <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo form_error("fullname"); ?></span>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username">
      <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo form_error("username"); ?></span>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo form_error("email"); ?></span>
      <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Password">
      <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo form_error("pass"); ?></span>
   <!--    <input type="password" name="pass1" placeholder="Retype Password"> -->
      <ul>
      <p1>Gender</p1>
      <select name="gender" id="gender" class="pilihan">
        <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo form_error("gender"); ?></span>
        <option value="men">Male</option>
        <option value="women">Female</option></select>
      </ul>
      <ul>
      <p1>Occupation</p1>
      <li><input type="radio" name="job" value="doctor" id="doctor" checked> Doctor<br></li>
      <span class="text-danger"> <?php echo form_error("job"); ?></span>
      <li><input type="radio" name="job" value="nurse" id="nurse"> Nurse<br></li>
    </ul>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/user/login.css">
      <a href="<?php echo base_url('c_register/do_insert'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg active" role="button">Primary link</a>
  </form>
```

my controller code :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class C_register extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_register');
    }

    // function index()
    // {
    //  $this->template->load('static','register');
    // }

    function do_insert(){
        // $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'firstname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'lastname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fullname', 'fullname', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'pass', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'gender', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('job', 'job', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            //true
            $data = array(
            'firstname' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
            'lastname' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
            'fullname' => $this->input->post('fullname'),
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'pass' => $this->input->post('pass'),
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'job' => $this->input->post('job')
            );
            $this->m_register->InsertData($data);
            echo "success";
        } else {
            //false
            // $this->index();
            echo "failed";
        }
    }
?>
```

my model code :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class M_register extends CI_Model {

    public function InsertData($data){
        $this->db->insert("member", $data);

    }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Before `if ($this->form_validation->run()) {` line, try to capture posted data using `print_r($_POST);die();`. Does it get any or all the posted data?

Answer (score 0):

With your current implementation, you have hidden any errors you might be getting.

So to see them, quickly, you need to load the form helper and add the line

```
echo validation_errors();
```

Just before you run the validation, just so you can see what is going on.

OR you can view the post data by doing a `var_dump($_POST);` in the same location